# Binomial theorem: Find $\sum_{r=0}^n3^r\binom{n}r$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find

$$\sum_{r=0}^n3^r\binom{n}r$$

When I tried to do it I got

$$1 + 3n + 3^2\cdot \frac{n(n-1)}2 + \ldots + 3^{n-1}\cdot n + 3^n$$

but I couldn't equate it to $4^n$ which is the answer I got by substituting $n$ for various numbers.

Can you tell me the correct mathematical way of getting the answer?

Comment: n sigma r=0  3^r nCr

Comment: I took the liberty of changing your $_nC_r$ notation to the preferable $\binom{n}r$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the binomial theorem. It says that

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}rx^ry^{n-r}\;;\tag{1}$$

now let $x=3$ and $y=1$, and see that the righthand side of $(1)$ is exactly your sum, while the lefthand side is indeed $4^n$.